# Can't define a path to an image

Tags: java, image, path, embedded-resource

I imported an image into Eclipse, in the same package as this class:

```
public class mainWindow extends JFrame {
    public mainWindow() {
    Image bg = // \mainPackage\ShittyPlane.png;
    Graphics2D g2d;
    this.setSize(500,500);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle("GameTest");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
  }
}
```

How do I define the image path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is part of you source and is packed into jar later for distribution i would sucgest you get a stream to the image using [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("mainPackage/ShittyPlane.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
```

this aproache will also work in if you run the program from your IDE

If you plan to locate the image using a a File chooser then go with @Pescis's answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do to load an image from a specific file is:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/mainPackage/ShittyPlane.png")); //I'm guessing this is the path to your image..
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

For more info you can read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) on working with images.